# Akka.net persistence actor doesn't get connection string from Fallback Config?

Tags: akka, akka.net, akka-cluster, akka-persistence, akka-persistent-fsm

I have my main hocon config in app.config file and try to set connection string from code behind using fallback config. but when actor system start it doesn't working. here is my hocon config and C# code as below. Can someone help me please?

Hocon config i have comment out connnection-string to take it from fallback config
        akka.persistence {

```
      journal {
        plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.sql-server"                
        sql-server {
              class = "Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Journal.SqlServerJournal, Akka.Persistence.SqlServer"
              plugin-dispatcher = "akka.actor.default-dispatcher"

              # connection string used for database access
              # connection-string = "Data Source=ES-NB-046\\MSSQLSERVER_2014;Initial Catalog=PSAkka;User ID=sa;Password=1qaz2wsx@;"
              # can alternativly specify: connection-string-name

              # default SQL timeout
              connection-timeout = 30s

              # SQL server schema name
              schema-name = dbo

              # persistent journal table name
              table-name = EventJournal

              # initialize journal table automatically
              auto-initialize = on

              timestamp-provider = "Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common.Journal.DefaultTimestampProvider, Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common"
              metadata-table-name = Metadata
        }
      }
```

C# code behind file

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {

    var mainConfig = ConfigurationFactory.Load();

    string connectionString = @"akka.persistence.journal.sql-server.connection-string = ""Data Source=Data Source=ES-NB-046\\MSSQLSERVER_2014;Initial Catalog=PSAkka;User ID=sa;Password=1qaz2wsx@;""";
    //string text1 = @"akka.persistence.journal.sql-server.abc = ""Data Source=Data Source=ES-NB-046\\MSSQLSERVER_2014;Initial Catalog=PSAkka;User ID=sa;Password=1qaz2wsx@;""";

    var conStringConfig = ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(connectionString);

    mainConfig = mainConfig.WithFallback(conStringConfig);

    System = ActorSystem.Create("Game", mainConfig);

    PlayerCoordinator = System.ActorOf<PlayerCoordinatorActor>("PlayerCoordinator");
```

Answer (score 0):

Connection string on code behind is having error of two time having data source

string connectionString = @"akka.persistence.journal.sql-server.connection-string = ""Data Source=Data Source=ES-NB-046\MSSQLSERVER_2014;Initial Catalog=PSAkka;User ID=sa;Password=1qaz2wsx@;""";

after that it works it is my fault

see the thread https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/2565